# C# Asp.net Site.css missing a portion when compiled

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I added some css to format a table in Asp.net, in the editor it looks exactly how I want, but when I start my application the css for the table is missing when I inspect the source, does anyone know what I'm doing wrong, is it a problem in the designer or with my code?

My Site.css in visual studio

```
/* Move down content because we have a fixed navbar that is 50px tall */
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Wrapping element */
/* Set some basic padding to keep content from hitting the edges */
.body-content {
    padding-left: 1px;
    padding-right: 1px;
}

/* Set widths on the form inputs since otherwise they're 100% wide */
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}

/* Tables */
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
table{
    width:100%;
}
tr:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #eee;
}

tr:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: #fff;
}

th{
    color: white !important; 
    background-color: black !important;
}
/* Responsive: Portrait tablets and up */
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .jumbotron {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .body-content {
        padding: 0;
    }
}
```

Site.css when I inspect it using Opera inspector

```
/* Move down content because we have a fixed navbar that is 50px tall */
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Wrapping element */
/* Set some basic padding to keep content from hitting the edges */
.body-content {
    padding-left: 1px;
    padding-right: 1px;
}

/* Set widths on the form inputs since otherwise they're 100% wide */
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}


/* Responsive: Portrait tablets and up */
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .jumbotron {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .body-content {
        padding: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment- likely a caching issue. Try in an incognito browser and see if you still have the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Probably You are forgot to give the class file name exactly as u called "body-content" name try to give the exact name in ur class like this : cssclass="body-content"  it will work, if it is a external css give the external link in your head section of ur page.